# Getting warning 'baseName' is deprecated. Can I use bootJar.archiveFileName in place of bootJar.baseName in gradle 7.4.2 for spring-boot projects?

Tags: spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using spring-boot 3. My gradle version is 7.4.2. I get this warning `'baseName' is deprecated`. Can I use `bootJar.archiveFileName` in place of `bootJar.baseName`? If I use archiveFileName, should I add the extension `.jar` at end?

[image]